# Erro ao tentar submeter formulário com arquivo por AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, arquivo, imagem, upload

Tenho o seguinte código que implementei de teste antes de colocar no meu projeto:

**index.php**

```
 <form method="post" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input name="nome" type="text"/>
 <input name="img" type="file"/>
 <button> Enviar</button>
 </form>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
    $('#formulario').submit(function(e)
    {
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "recebe.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert(result);
            }
        });     
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

**recebe.php**

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $value)
{
    echo $value." - ";
}

foreach($_FILES['img'] as $value)
{
    echo $value." + ";
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],  'teste.jpg')) {
    echo "Sucesso";
}
```

O objetivo é fazer o upload da imagem sem ter que recarregar a página. Tentei criando um `FormData` e enviando ele por `ajax`, mas o `alert` do retorno sequer é exibido. Não sei qual é o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui assim:

```
var dados = new FormData(this);

$.ajax(
{
    url: 'recebe.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data:  dados,
    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
         alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
        // Em caso de erro
    }          
});
```

Answer (score -1):

O parâmetro é method, não type:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: "recebe.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: No AJAX usasse `type` par informar o tipo do formulário. Esse não é o erro.